# Unable to get the clicked row value of kendo grid using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have an onChange event for kendogrid where i am able to get the clicked row values into the variable and now i am try to do it for onClick event instead of onChange and i had made the below changes

```
function onChange(arg) {
    debugger;
    var grid = $("#divCallLogHistory").data("kendoGrid");
    if (grid.select()) {
        var selectedItem = grid.dataItem(grid.select());
        if (selectedItem != null) {
            $('.k-animation-container').hide();
            $('.k-tooltip').hide();
            $('.modal-dialog').css({ top: 0, left: 0 });
            $('#divpopupwidth').addClass('popupmaxwidth');
            $('#divpopupcontent').html('');
            $('#popuptitle').html(' ');
            $('#divpopupcontent').load(appURL + "/Data/Details", {}, function () {
                GetProviderValidityDetails(selectedItem.ProviderID);
                SetProviderDetails(selectedItem.ProviderID);
                $('#spandummypopup').attr('data-target', '#divopenpopup');
                $('#spandummypopup').trigger('click');

            });

        }

    }
}

title: "Name", field: "Name", template: "<a class='anchorNavLinkStyle' href='javascript:void(0)' data-ID='#= ID #' onclick='onChange(this)'>#= Name#</a>", width: 150
```

added onclick='onChange(this) and calling the function onChange(this) using this function i am getting  `var selectedItem = grid.dataItem(grid.select());` selecteditem to null

Answer (score 0):

Take this example how to get selected row:

```
function onChange(e) {
    var rows = e.sender.select();
    rows.each(function (e) {
        var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
        var dataItem = grid.dataItem(this);

        console.log(dataItem);
    })
};
```

Comment: even my code is also working for onchange but if i use the same code of onclick instead of onchange i am not getting the selected row data into var selectedItem = grid.dataItem(grid.select());